# APN settings in A500 with dongle

Tags: 3.2-honeycomb, apn

I own an A500 without 3G and a ZTE LF627 USB dongle. I donwloaded the `thor_3g_patch_v14.2` and flawlessly installed it. I also had to unlock my dongle (tested from computer, works...).

Now I connected it to my Iconia. It shows the blue *roaming* light, and seems to be ready for connection.

How do I set up APNs in Honeycomb 3.2? I found that a new settings menu "Tethering/portable hotspot" appeared after ROM patching, but I see no more menus for setting up APNs. From ConnectBot I can also see /dev/ppp

Can you help me with that? I can't even install those applications from the market that enable setting APNs because Google forbids me.

[Add]Interesting ADB output

```
~ # rild
rild
insmod: can't open '/system/lib/modules/usb_wwan.ko'
insmod: can't open '/system/lib/modules/option.ko'
chmod: /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory
chmod: /dev/ttyUSB1: No such file or directory
chmod: /dev/ttyUSB2: No such file or directory
dlopen failed: Cannot load library: load_library[1108]: Library '/system/lib/libhuawei-ril.so' not found
```

maybe I'm missing some kernel modules.